# Remote db connection from another remote ip perl

Tags: mysql, perl, remote-server

I am trying to connect one remote server where I have installed MySQL  but it is taking localhost 
Remote server where mySQL is installed: 131.116.220.228
Remote server from where db needs to be connected: 131.116.220.220 ('ov046hanpgate01.ddc.teliasonera.net')

```
use DBI;
print "Testing 1\n";

$DSN="DATABASE=MySQL80;port=3306;host=131.116.220.228";
print "Testing 2\n";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:$DSN", "ShrutiTest", "Shruti@92", {PrintError => 0})
or die "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;
print "Testing 3\n";

$dbh->disconnect;
```

> error: Couldn't connect to database: Host 'ov046hanpgate01.ddc.teliasonera.net' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server at D:\Integrations\OWF\Scripts\test27july.pl line 6.

Comment: You need to check your permissions. MySQL has strict permissions when it comes to remote hosts, so be sure you have a user that matches the hostname after the `@`. `root@localhost` != `root@%`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to allow the user ShrutiTest to connect from the ip where you are running the script, viz. 131.116.220.220

It can be done at the MySQL server by any admin:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ShrutiTest'@'131.116.220.220'
```

Comment: And access from the ip?

Comment: SELECT * from information_schema.user_privileges where grantee like "'ShrutiTest'%" group by grantee

run this to check

Comment: It is returning me 1 row with yes response

Answer (score 0):

This syntax `"DBI:mysql:database=$db;host=$host;port=$port"` worked for me in the perl script to connect to a remote MySQL DB from an Unix server.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the same. Code used is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;

## mysql user database name
$db ="Buffering";
## mysql database user name
$user = "ShrutiBuffer";

## mysql database password
$pass = "Shruti1234";

## user hostname : This should be "localhost" but it can be diffrent too
$host="131.116.220.228";
$port="3306";
## SQL query
$query = "select * from buffering.insert_data";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db;host=$host;port=$port",$user, $pass);

$sqlQuery  = $dbh->prepare($query)
or die "Can't prepare $query: $dbh->errstr\n";

$sqlQuery->execute
or die "can't execute the query: $sqlQuery->errstr";

print "values are:: ";
while (@row= $sqlQuery->fetchrow_array()) {
 print join(", ", @row), "\n";

}

$sqlQuery->finish;
exit(0);
```

Comment: So you fixed it by connecting to a completely different database? Is that really a fix? For this answer to be useful to anyone else, you really need to explain how you found a solution and what that solution was. Just dumping some code here isn't really helpful.